# How do I access the elements within innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
list.innerHTML = `
    <p id="text" class="text">${toDoItem.task}</p>
    <div id="taskListBtn">
      <span id="button-tick-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons tick-style">check_circle</span>
      <span id="button-edit-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons edit-style">edit</span>
      <span id="button-remove-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons remove-style">delete</span>
    </div>
    `;
```

Hi, how do I go about accessing the paragraph element within a innerHTML if I want to addClassList to it? Or I shouldn't have used innerHTML in this case?

Comment: First of, you cannot have duplicate ID elements. In a ToDo list you'll have duplicate `#text` elements and no, you cannot target the *one you want* using an ID.

Comment: I think you should use `.childNodes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the child of the `list` element afterwards:

```
const p = list.querySelector('#text');
p.classList.add('foo');
```

But you shouldn't be interpolating HTML strings directly like you're doing here, if the interpolated strings come from user input (like `.task`), because that'll allow for arbitrary code execution and isn't very elegant. I'd suggest instead, assigning the `innerHTML` *without* the user-inputted text, then insert the user's text by selecting the element(s) that need it afterwards:

```
list.innerHTML = `
    <p id="text" class="text"></p>
    <div id="taskListBtn">
      <span id="button-tick-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons tick-style">check_circle</span>
      <span id="button-edit-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons edit-style">edit</span>
      <span id="button-remove-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons remove-style">delete</span>
    </div>
    `;
const p = list.querySelector('#text');
p.textContent = toDoItem.task;
```

(I'm assuming that the `id`s are trustworthy, and aren't directly from user text input, or are numbers)

That said, there's another issue - dynamic IDs are quite a code smell, and duplicate IDs are invalid HTML anyway. It would be better to remove the IDs entirely and use classes or data attributes instead. For example, since it sounds like the `list` is the container for an item, that'd probably be the most appropriate element to put the ID into:

```
list.dataset.id = toDoItem.id;
```

and remove the IDs from everywhere else.

(`list` sounds like a misleading variable name, though, since you're assigning it the content of just a *single* item - maybe call it `listItemDiv` instead, or something like that?)

Comment: That's a dodo List! you cannot have duplicated `#text` items.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not the best solution.
A ToDo is a list and you cannot have duplicated IDs `#text` elements.
Instead wrap the all inside a common ancestor Element.

With the following example you don't even need the use of IDs as a reference to a specific item, since all the items have it's own event bound upfront:

```js
const ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);


const newTask = (toDoItem) => {

  const List = EL("#todo");

  const Task = ELNew("LI", {
    className: "todo-task"
  });
  
  const Text = ELNew("INPUT", {
    className: "todo-text",
    type: "text",
    value: toDoItem.task
  });
  
  const BtnCheck = ELNew("BUTTON", {
    className: "todo-btn todo-btn--check",
    type: "button",
    textContent: "Check",
    onclick: () => Text.classList.toggle("is-checked")
  });
  
  const BtnRemove = ELNew("BUTTON", {
    className: "todo-btn todo-btn--remove",
    type: "button",
    textContent: "Delete",
    onclick: () => Task.remove()
  });

  Task.append(Text, BtnCheck, BtnRemove);
  List.append(Task);

};

const toDos = [
  {task: "Ask a question"},
  {task: "Got an answer"}
];

toDos.forEach(newTask);
```

```css
.todo { padding: 0; }
.todo-task { display: flex; }
.todo-text { flex: 1;}
.is-checked { color: green; text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<ul id="todo" class="todo"></ul>
```

Comment: Hey Roko, thanks for the answer. Could you explain what the first 2 lines mean? I'm very new to JS so I am not very sure...

Comment: Hei @ChiamMin ! The first two lines are helper functions I often use when I want to later, without much fuss do: 1 create a new element, 2. get an element in the DOM by its selector. See later in the code i.e: the use of `NewEL("tagName", propertiesObject)` - quite neat, you pass a desired tagName for the new element and all the Element properties without much repetition. Same for `EL("#someID")` instead of doing `someElememnt.querySelector("#someID")`

Answer (score -1):

```
list.innerHTML = `
    <p id="text" class="text">${toDoItem.task}</p>
    <div id="taskListBtn">
      <span id="button-tick-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons tick-style">check_circle</span>
      <span id="button-edit-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons edit-style">edit</span>
      <span id="button-remove-${toDoItem.id}" class="material-icons remove-style">delete</span>
    </div>
    `;

const addClasses = ['class1', 'class2'];
const paragtaph = list.querySelector('p');
paragtaph.className += ` ${addClasses.join(' ')}`;
```

You query the paragraph and then add the classes you like by joining the array of classes you want.