# getElementsByClassName() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I want the following code to create a close button and append it to each list item. But since I have more than one list, I want it to only apply to the list with a specific class name, for example class="ToDo-List".

I am creating a To Do list where the user can add and delete items.

I tried using getElementsByClassName() but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if I'm applying it the wrong way or the problem is in the HTML.

Below is the code I currently have:

HTML (where should I place the class, in each li element?):

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="to-do-header">
    <h2 class="table-title">To Do</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="What do you want to do?">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
  </div>
  
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li>Wake up</li>
    <li>Meeting with the team</li>
    <li>Have an amazing lunch</li>
    <li>Finsish the project</li>
    <li>Get some pizza</li>
    <li>Go to sleep</li>
  </ul>
```

JavaScript (the code I'm referring to is the first section but I didn't know if the rest might have something to do with the problem so I included all the code for that list):

```
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly, *exactly*, does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: why do you create elements and add them to the DOM and then select those elements to add an event listener? Just add the event when you create the element.

Comment: Where is the call that's having the problem? The only call I see is for `getElementsByClassName("close")`.

Comment: So all that code and the issue you have is you are selecting all the lis in the page instead of just the lis of one UL? So just use querySelectorAll with the selector that selects that list and the lis.

Comment: Make up your mind -- either use `.onclick=` or `addEventListener()`. For modern code, prefer the latter.

Comment: "where should i place the class, in each li element?" The class name `ToDo-List` sounds like it should be the entire list, not an individual LI. Each LI would be `class="todo-item"`

Comment: You should keep an existing list inside an Array in JS and populate the DOM. Use the same functions to create new elements. So basically, empty the HTML. Back to the drawing board. Also, to preserve the list you might want to store it inside LocalStorage. There's so many cool and simple implementation examples of to-do lists both [here on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73199942/383904) , and on the WWW. Seems like you went the harder way... learn from other people's code. If you understand it - you own it.

Comment: `const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li");`

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, that worked. I'm a bit new to Javascript so I'm sorry if the question was not correctly formulated. My problem was that when using getElementsByClassName() nothing happened at all.

Comment: and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080653/383904) ... any many many more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem you have is document.getElementsByTagName selected every tag on the page. If you want to limit it to just the one list, you need to either select the list with getElementById first OR use querySelectorAll()

```
const list = document.getElementById("myUL");
const listItems = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

// or better option

const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li");
```

You have a lot of repetitive code. Pull it out into reusable functions so you are not copy and pasting things. Simplify your events with event delegation.

```js
function addCloseBtn (li) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  const txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  button.className = "close";
  button.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(button);
}

function createLi (ul, text) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const txt = document.createTextNode(text);
  li.appendChild(txt);
  addCloseBtn(li);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

// Loop over the existing li elements and add the close button
document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li").forEach(addCloseBtn);

// find your list
const myList = document.querySelector("#myUL");

// add a click handler to the elemenet and we will use event delegation
myList.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  // look if the what was clicked was our button
  const btn = event.target.closest('button.close');
  
  // if e have the button remove it
  if (btn) btn.closest('li').remove();
});


function newElement(){

  // get the text
  const text = document.querySelector('#myInput').value.trim();
  
  /// verify they added text
  if (!text) {
    alert('error');
    return;
  }
  
  // create your li
  createLi(myList, text);
}
```

```css
.close {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="to-do-header">
  <h2 class="table-title">To Do</h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="What do you want to do?">
  <button onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</button>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Wake up</li>
  <li>Meeting with the team</li>
  <li>Have an amazing lunch</li>
  <li>Finsish the project</li>
  <li>Get some pizza</li>
  <li>Go to sleep</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided does seem to work on my machine (using Firefox), at least on its own. Adding a second duplicate list section seems to portray the problem you're describing, where it's only adding items to a single list.

I would recommend using a similar technique you did with your removal events. In `newElement()`, use the event given to you (making your function `newElement(event)` instead) and operating on the appropriate elements relative to that event's target.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).